# App crashing sometimes when transitioning between views: how to debug constraints?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, transition, nslayoutconstraint

I perform a transition between views with an animation. It sometimes works, and it also sometimes causes a crash and I don't understand why. I have my code within a `@try-@catch` block but no exception is retrieved in `@catch`. I simply get an app crash with a SIGABRT signal and the following log:

> 2015-09-23 10:03:43.420 My App[1510:528283] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: 
>       When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>
> 2015-09-23 10:03:43.421 My App[1510:528283] *** Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.16/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:590

I don't understand why it sometimes works and other times it crashes, and I don't understand how can I debug this, please I need help.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

This is the method that seems to cause the app crashes:

```
- (void)switchToMainView
{
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                     duration:1.0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    @try {
                        if ([self.secView superview]) {
                            [self setMainView];
                            [self.secView removeFromSuperview];
                            [self.view addSubview:self.mainView];
                            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.secView];
                        }
                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception) {
                        NSLog(@"exception: %@", exception.description);
                    }
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    if (finished) {
                        @try {
                            [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                            [self setMessage];
                        }
                        @catch (NSException *exception) {
                            NSLog(@"exception: %@", exception.description);
                        }
                    }
                }];
}
```

And the `setMessage` method that is called in the completion block:

```
- (void)setMessage
{
   UIView *messageView = nil;

   @try {
      messageView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessageView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];

      messageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.messagesContainerView.frame.size.width, self.messagesContainerView.frame.size.height);
      [self.messagesContainerView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
      [self.messagesContainerView addSubview:messageView];
   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"exception: %@", exception.description);
   }
}
```

where `self.messagesContainerView` is a subview of `self.mainView` in the first method.

Thanks again

**EDIT 2:**

This is the last crash information I managed to get:

> Date/Time:       2015-09-24 10:01:13 +0000 OS Version:      iPhone OS
>   9.0 (13A344) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  SIGABRT Exception Codes: #0 at 0x34de0d24 Crashed
>   Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up
>   layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x22ee786b 0x22df2000 + 1005675 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x345e6dff 0x345e0000 + 28159 2   CoreFoundation
>   0x22ee7741 0x22df2000 + 1005377 3   Foundation
>   0x23c772ab 0x23be0000 + 619179 4   UIKit
>   0x277ced17 0x26fe7000 + 8289559 5   UIKit
>   0x270f8b1b 0x26fe7000 + 1121051 6   UIKit
>   0x270f898d 0x26fe7000 + 1120653 7   UIKit
>   0x270f88a7 0x26fe7000 + 1120423 8   UIKit
>   0x277cee6d 0x26fe7000 + 8289901 9   UIKit
>   0x270f878f 0x26fe7000 + 1120143 10  My App
>   0x000423c5 0x11000 + 201669 11  UIKit
>   0x277d479d 0x26fe7000 + 8312733 12  Foundation
>   0x23c29c81 0x23be0000 + 302209 13  UIKit
>   0x270fbaa9 0x26fe7000 + 1133225 14  UIKit
>   0x277d49d9 0x26fe7000 + 8313305 15  UIKit
>   0x270fc78b 0x26fe7000 + 1136523 16  Foundation
>   0x23c29c81 0x23be0000 + 302209 17  UIKit
>   0x270fbaa9 0x26fe7000 + 1133225 18  UIKit
>   0x270fc487 0x26fe7000 + 1135751 19  UIKit
>   0x277d4fa5 0x26fe7000 + 8314789 20  UIKit
>   0x272edfa9 0x26fe7000 + 3174313 21  UIKit
>   0x26ff56bb 0x26fe7000 + 59067 22  QuartzCore
>   0x268c167d 0x268b4000 + 54909 23  QuartzCore
>   0x268bcd79 0x268b4000 + 36217 24  QuartzCore
>   0x268bcc09 0x268b4000 + 35849 25  QuartzCore
>   0x268bc129 0x268b4000 + 33065 26  QuartzCore
>   0x268bbdeb 0x268b4000 + 32235 27  QuartzCore
>   0x268b55bf 0x268b4000 + 5567 28  CoreFoundation
>   0x22eaa0f1 0x22df2000 + 753905 29  CoreFoundation
>   0x22ea83e7 0x22df2000 + 746471 30  CoreFoundation
>   0x22ea8825 0x22df2000 + 747557 31  CoreFoundation
>   0x22dfb1e9 0x22df2000 + 37353 32  CoreFoundation
>   0x22dfafdd 0x22df2000 + 36829 33  GraphicsServices
>   0x2c09faf9 0x2c096000 + 39673 34  UIKit
>   0x2706018d 0x26fe7000 + 496013 35  My App
>   0x000d7d69 0x11000 + 814441 36  libdyld.dylib
>   0x34d11873 0x34d0f000 + 10355
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x34de0d24
>   0x34dcc000 + 85284 1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34d78f51
>   0x34d2e000 + 307025 2   My App                              0x001abebf
>   0x11000 + 1683135 3   CoreFoundation                      0x22ee7ba9
>   0x22df2000 + 1006505 4   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x345e7087 0x345e0000 + 28807 5   libc++abi.dylib
>   0x33dcce17 0x33db6000 + 93719 6   libc++abi.dylib
>   0x33dcc8f7 0x33db6000 + 92407 7   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x345e6f47 0x345e0000 + 28487 8   CoreFoundation
>   0x22dfb26f 0x22df2000 + 37487 9   CoreFoundation
>   0x22dfafdd 0x22df2000 + 36829 10  GraphicsServices
>   0x2c09faf9 0x2c096000 + 39673 11  UIKit
>   0x2706018d 0x26fe7000 + 496013 12  My App
>   0x000d7d69 0x11000 + 814441 13  libdyld.dylib
>   0x34d11873 0x34d0f000 + 10355

Comment: you need to show us what did you do in code

Comment: @dopcn sure, I edited my question

Comment: You are removing a superview with `[self.secView removeFromSuperview];` and then two lines later you are moving it to the back with `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.secView];`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Abizern You're right, there shouldn't be need to call `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.secView];`... actually that code snippet is not complete, `secView` and `mainView` can be switched several times according to my app logic

Comment: So the code in your question isn't complete? Not much use to us in helping with your problem.

Comment: @Abizern you're right... that's why initially I was asking for a clue for debugging errors similar to `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.`, not actually a particular solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code It's hard to debug the actual problem. The probably causes are:

- You are adding a constraint to a view that is not a superview of the constrained class.
- You are adding a constraint to a view that has not been added as a subview yet - and so is not in the view hierarchy.

As to fixing it. I managed to create a project which crashes in this way, and correctly found the mistake by adding a symbolic breakpoint as the error suggests:

[image]

So try this and see where your problem is coming from.