# Unable to debug layout constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

My app is crashing when transitioning some `UIViews`, and I'm not able to find the cause. I get this error in the logs console of Xcode:

> 2015-09-23 10:03:43.420 My App[1510:528283] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>
> 2015-09-23 10:03:43.421 My App[1510:528283] *** Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.16/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:590

I don't know how to debug this, i don't understand that `Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.`. I didn't find how to do this in the documentation and any example, could somebody tell me how could I do?

Comment: need the code you used to add constraints

Answer (score 3):

This happens for example when you added constraints on a view and the view itself isn't added to another view yet. Not making sense

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad

  let newView = setupCandyView()
  view.addSubview(newView)
}


func setupCandyView() -> UIView {
  let container = UIView()

  let button = UIButton()
  container.addSubview(button)

  // you are adding constarints here
  // but container isn't added to the view yet

  addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: container,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: 0))

  return container
}
```

Just add a symbolic breakpoint to catch where the error throws.

[image: Symbolic Breakpoint Example]

Answer (score 1):

when you add a constraint  between views, both views must be in the same hierarchy.

That means that both views *must* share a common superview.

Check your constraint code to be sure that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find and debig something like: `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x17c2a320 V:[UIView:0x1796f8e0(121)]>`?

Comment: Yes, but I sometimes get this error and sometimes I don't, I'm not able to find what constraint is causing the crash with a "normal" breakpoint...

Comment: Unfortunately, if you can't find it with access to all your code; I can't find it without access to your code.

Comment: It's not easy to explain here and I'd need to post a lot of code and explanation, I did some in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743403/app-crashing-sometimes-when-transitioning-between-views-how-to-debug-constraint ... I've found the constraint that is causing the crash but it only happens sometimes and I don't understand why, and in code it is always removed, created, and added again...

Comment: Could it be because `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` hasn't finished before I set the subview?